# discord.py | Ошибка взаимодействия c кнопкой

Tags: python, бот, discord, discord.py, button

В общем, есть код в котором я написал простую команду с кнопками, при нажатии на которые возникает "Ошибка взаимодействия" под сообщением бота. Пробовал решить проблему с помощью ChatGPT, но он не помог. Буду рад любым попыткам помочь мне в этой дилемме.) Закомментировал для удобства:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class MyCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def my_command1(self, ctx):
        # Создание кнопок
        yes_button = discord.ui.Button(style=discord.ButtonStyle.green, label='Да')
        no_button = discord.ui.Button(style=discord.ButtonStyle.red, label='Нет')
        # Создание сообщения и добавление кнопок
        embed = discord.Embed(title='Вы согласны?', description='Нажмите на кнопку, чтобы ответить')
        try:
            view = discord.ui.View()
            view.add_item(yes_button)
            view.add_item(no_button)
            view.timeout = None
            message = await ctx.send(embed=embed, view=view)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Ошибка при отправке сообщения: {e}")

        # Функция, которая вызывается при нажатии на кнопку "Да"
        async def yes_callback(interaction: discord.Interaction):
            await interaction.response.send_message('Вы выбрали Да!', ephemeral=False)

        # Функция, которая вызывается при нажатии на кнопку "Нет"
        async def no_callback(interaction: discord.Interaction):
            await interaction.response.send_message('Вы выбрали Нет!', ephemeral=False)

        # Установка функций-обработчиков событий для кнопок
        yes_button.callback = yes_callback
        no_button.callback = no_callback

        # Добавление View в очередь с удалением
        if view:
            self.bot.add_view(view)
```